# So I've been taking some time off from work to _______________

Tags: idiomatic-language

I recently got divorced from my wife of ten years, so I've been taking some time off from work to ____________________

1. To try and recover.
2. To try and get back up again.
3. To try and get back on track.
4. To try and pick myself up (again).
5. To clear my mind.
6. To find myself again.

Would all my suggestions be grammatical and natural to use in this exact context? Do you prefer one of them?

Comment: Is it the ten years of marriage that you are recovering from, or the strain of the divorce?

Comment: ...The divorce.

Comment: You could use any of your suggestions but it would be helpful to the reader if you spelled things out. **...to try to/and recover from the strain of the divorce.**

Comment: While acceptable your usage of ‘and’ is a colloquialism. “To try to” is more technically correct than “To try and”.

Comment: If asked for a preference I would suggest 6 as the most constructive and least open to being read as a criticism of your ex.